# Get the active and inactive values from the Picklist

Tags: picklist, describefieldresult

I'm trying to get the active and inactive values, especially the inactive ones, from a picklist to activate them via code. The problem is that I can only get the active values.

```
List<String> pickListValuesActive   = new List<String>();
List<String> pickListValuesInactive = new List<String>();

Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = ObjectApiName.PicklistApiName.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple) {
   if(pickListVal.isActive()) {
       pickListValuesActive.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
   } else {
       pickListValuesInactive.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
   }
}
```

I thought about using a trigger after inserting values to make a treatment, but from what I researched it won't work because these picklist values are metadata.

Please, does anyone know if is there any way I can get the inactive values from a picklist and activate them via code?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find active and inactive picklist values from picklist field?

Comment: Exactly, I want to take both active and inactive values. Mainly inactive ones, because I will activate them via code.

Comment: How are you going to activate them by code? - Metadata API?

Comment: I thought I could set the **isActive()** property to the value of **true**, but I also don't know if it is possible, because my initial idea is to visualize this inactive data to see what are the possible treatments to be done.

Comment: Please edit your post to change "objects" to "values".  When you say "objects" it is confusing.

Comment: Done, I already changed "objects" to "values" to facilitate understanding.